# How to get Visual Studio Code to recognize Java Script functions?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

In NetBeans I just added a comment with `global`, e.g.

```
/* global myLibrary */
```

in order to get it to recognize my functions.

However, this seems not to work in VS Code. For example, if I have a function named `myFunction` in the `myLibrary` module, when I click on "Go To Definition", it tells me that there was "No definition found for myFunction".

So how do I get VS Code to recognize my function?

Answer (score 0):

I believe VSCode does not provide this feature by default. You will have to define the configuration yourself if your project has mixed content in it. I use VSCode for Angular 2 (using ng-cli) so it has all the setup generated for me (i can goto definition if it is valid).

have a look at these two links, hope this helps you:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_automatic-type-acquisition
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_what-is-jsconfigjson

Comment: Thanks. Looking at [1], I got the impression that all what is needed is a `jsconfig.json` file with `{  "compilerOptions": {  "target": "ES6"  }}` in my root directory. Unfortunately, that did not help.

[1] https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_what-is-jsconfigjson

Comment: Strangely enough, it is also stated that "For common setups a `jsconfig.json` file is not required, however, there are situations when you will want to add a `jsconfig.json`." [2] I am really lost with this documentation. [2] https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript

Comment: A website that generates vector (SVG) diagrams. I have some PHP and JavaScript files. I am using no third party libraries.

Comment: @Daniel these days, projects which contain a front-end component are largely expected to be written with modules, where anything not expressly exported from the file would not be treated as global, whether you told it to or not. A lot of the more JS-centric tools are working on the assumption that you are exporting functions/values in one of several ways, whether or not you're using extra build steps (which will/won't be needed depending on the environment and the choice of export).

Comment: @Norguard not sure I follow. I already have my functions in a module using a "module pattern". Is that enough? Or is the idea that I have to use another library and extend upon it?

Comment: A module pattern that is either Node `module.exports` or ES6 `export ___`, not the old IIFEs.